# how can I get my normal vim initialization when I execute sudo vim?

Tags: linux, vim, sudo

I have an alias defined
`alias svi='sudo /usr/bin/vim -i /home/jeff/.viminfo -u /home/jeff/.vimrc'` but when I type `svi myfile` I get

> Error detected while processing /home/jeff/.vimrc:
>   line    1:
>   E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect

It seems I need to force vim to scan my .vim directory before executing `call pathogen#infect()`  How do I do that, and in general, how can I make sure that when I run `sudo vim` I get the same environment that I would have by just running `vim`?

Comment: As a side note, if the reason you want `sudo vim` is to be able to edit root-owned files, you may look at Tim Pope's [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) plugin. It has a `SudoWrite` command which will allow you to overwrite a priviliged file from Vim started without privileges.

Comment: thanks I will try vim-eunuch, but I think understanding how to control initialization is still a worthy goal.

Comment: Have you installed Pathogen as root? My thought is that it is looking for the root user to have Pathogen installed. Perhaps you can give it the full path.

Comment: @Shadoath it turns out you were sort of on the right track, but I don't want to modify root's environment (in part because there are a half-dozen devops folk who need to do things as root on the system).  I just needed the secret sauce for getting vim to look at my own .vim directory.  Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I get my normal vim initialization when I execute sudo vim?

By using `$ sudo -e filename` instead of `$ sudo vim filename`.

That command will:

1. ask for your password (if the sudoers security policy requires it);
2. make a copy of `filename` in `/tmp/`;
3. open it *as you* with the first editor found by checking the following, in order: `$SUDO_EDITOR`, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and finally the list of editors specified in /etc/sudoers;
4. copy it back to the original filename on write.

Refer to `man sudo` and `man sudoers` for more information.

Comment: On most systems you can also do `sudoedit` instead of `sudo -e`.

Comment: As an added benefit, this is safer, since `$EDITOR` is run without root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

While I intend to accept @romainl's answer as the preferred solution (after he tweaks it a little), I took another crack at researching a solution to the error I was getting because I hate it when computers get the better of me.

It turns out the error has to do with how the vim `runtimepath` option resolves when running as root.  So to correct the error, I changed my alias slightly to `alias svi='sudo /usr/bin/vim -i /home/jeff/.viminfo -u /home/jeff/.svimrc'` and put the following three lines into /home/jeff/.svimrc

```
set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after,/home/jeff/.vim
source /etc/vimrc
source /home/jeff/.vimrc
```

I no longer get the error and my custom stuff seems to be working (so far).  But if I run into any other glitches, I will peruse `:help initialization` some more to see what else should go into my .svimrc file....